# How do I get rid of those ambiguous call errors with GoogleARCore Wrappers (CS0121)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, wrapper, camera-api

One error that Unity is pointing to is with GoogleARCore CameraApi with the following lines:

```
    public TrackingState GetTrackingState(IntPtr cameraHandle)
    {
        ApiTrackingState apiTrackingState = ApiTrackingState.Stopped;
        ExternApi.ArCamera_getTrackingState(m_NativeSession.SessionHandle,
            cameraHandle, ref apiTrackingState);
        return apiTrackingState.ToTrackingState();
    }
```

The error Unity points to is the return statement.  As this is a snippet from a GoogleARCore, it should be fair to say that there should not be any errors.  However, Unity is pointing towards this as an error?  There are more of these similar errors with GoogleARCore Wrappers.

Comment: Could you add the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I figured out some way to fix those errors.  Reinstalling GoogleARCore and a few Unity crashes later, it worked out.  It kept reporting that I had some Unity bug issue.

Thanks for listening ...